RS232 (FT232R) - Different TX voltages with the same adapter under Windows and Linux
I have a USB to RS232 adapter cable (FT232R) that I use with Windows and Linux. Therefore I use a Python script with pyserial.
Under Windows, the lowest voltage during a data transfer is -6.2V and the highest voltage is 6.2V on the TX line. Communication with a connected device works perfectly here.
Under Linux I send exactly the same data (same python code), but the TX voltage is shifted upwards. The lowest voltage is -0.8V and the highest voltage is 11.8V. The communication fails here. When I measure over a 10k resistor the voltage is positive at the beginning and drops during transmission under Linux (see images).
How can I adjust the voltage under Linux (Ubuntu)?
The adapter cable is from W&T (https://wut.de/e-38011-ww-dade-000.php). Under Linux the adapter is recognized as "Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC".
Images can be found here: https://imgur.com/a/lB78S4a

I suspect a hardware issue. Please [edit] your question and add more information: Are you using Windows and Linux on the same computer with the same USB port? If not, add details about the two PCs. Show or describe in detail how you connect the probes and the device connected at the serial port. There might be some grounding issue or a capacitor that removes the DC offset...

Like @Bodo in the comments, I first thought "hardware issue", but then I realized it might also be USB power saving.
Since USB provides only +5V, any negative and higher-than-+5V voltages must be produced by a charge pump circuit in the adapter - and if that gets switched off in power saving mode, it could be fully drained when you open the port.
The datasheet indicates your adapter uses a FTDI FT232R serial converter chip. Here is the datasheet for it, straight from the chip manufacturer.
See the example USB to RS232 converter circuit in Chapter 7.1 on page 24: note that the RS232 level converter chip has a connection to the SLEEP# pin of the FT232R chip, suggesting that the level converter gets powered down when the main chip enters a power saving mode.
Since the UART interface of the actual FT232R chip can only supply 0V / +5V signal levels at most, it is clear that your adapter includes a level converter chip.
If your Linux runs on different hardware than your Windows, then it might even be a case of insufficient USB power output on the Linux system to keep the charge pumps of the level converter fully charged against the drain of your RS232 device.
See if adding a few seconds of delay between opening/initializing the port and the actual transmission changes things. If the problem is that the adapter starts in power saving mode, the delay after initializing the port might allow the adapter to come out of power saving mode and allow the charge pumps to charge up before starting communications.

Linux is running on another computer, but I used a second one to verify the problem. The same error occurs here too. I was able to use another FT232 adapter today and the error does not occur here, this one works perfectly. Therefore, it seems to be a specific problem of the manufacturer W&T and is related to the sleep mode, as you suspected. However, installing a delay does not help here.  Many thanks for your answer.
